# How do I install an external module from a wheel?

Tags: python, matplotlib, six

I'm trying to run someone else's script in Python 2.7 on Win7x64 (but 32-bit Python - I need it to be 2.7 to run `pyserial`, apparently). It starts with the following lines:

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
```

Which gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xxxxxx\Muddy Data Plot.py", line 9, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
    import six
ImportError: No module named six
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong, or how to fix it. The only thing I can find about `six` gives me something called a "wheel," which I can only install with something called `pip`, but I can't figure out how to use any of those things.  I think I got `pip` installed, but I can't figure out how to use it, or what the commands are.

Am I supposed to use the Windows command prompt with `pip`? Or the Python shell?  Do I need to import it first? I've added the `python` and `scripts` folder (which does contain something called `pip.exe`) to the Windows environment variables, to no effect. Am I supposed to put the wheel file somewhere in particular? I've rebooted about three times to make sure all the various changes took.

Can someone provide an explanation that doesn't assume a thorough knowledge of Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install pip on windows, follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows).

And then you run pip from the command prompt like `pip install six`, or maybe `pip.exe install six` as other answer states.

You can also just type `pip` (`pip.exe`?)into the command prompt terminal to get some helpful `pip` info.

Comment: So, apparently that installed six, and gave me a new error, this time "ImportError: matplotlib requires dateutil", but pip install dateutil" doesn't work            Also, none of the commands cause any output.  I type, and it just pauses and shows another command line.

Comment: Ok, I took a shot in the dark and typed "pip install matplotlib", in spite of having run the installer executable previously.  For no good reason, this time it worked.

Comment: Fun stuff. : ) I started learning python about a year ago. Mountains left to traverse.

Answer (score 1):

In the windows shell (make sure pip.exe is in your path)

```
pip.exe install six
```